# Inequality involving a geometric series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

Reading a book I can't see how to show the following inequality,

$$C\sum_{j,k,l}c_k d_l 2^{-\epsilon|jq+k| -\epsilon |jq+l| -\epsilon |k-l|} \leq \frac{C}{\epsilon} \sum_{k,l} c_kd_l2^{-\epsilon |k-l|}$$

$j,k,l$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$, $q>1$, $\epsilon \in (0, \frac{1}{4}]$ and $c_k, d_l >0$.

I guess that he is summing over the $j$ for fixed $k,l$ but the sum

$$\displaystyle \sum_i 2^{-\epsilon i}= \sum_i (\frac{1}{2^{\epsilon}})i = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^{\epsilon}}}$$

doesn't seem to be bounded by $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ to me.

The book is Fourier Analysis and non linear partial differential equations- Jean Yves Chemin Hajer Bahouri Raphael Danchin. And it is page 9.

Comment: Be carefull, the powers of $2$ in the triple summation is not integers as in the geometric sum, so you can not easily sum. On the other side, you should consider negative integers for $j,k,l$.

Comment: you are right, so it is even more complicated than what I thought.

Comment: The author continues in his book with the following,
 $ \frac{1}{\epsilon}\sum_{k,l}c_k  d_l 2^{-\epsilon |k-l|}\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}||c_k||_{l^p}||d_l||_{l^{p'}}$

He suggests to use Young's inequality (convolution) on Z with counting measure. So I am assuming that what he is doing is an $l^1$ $l^p$ convolution between $c_k$ and $2^{-\epsilon |k-l|}$ so this gives an l^p sequence that he integrate against $d_l$ which is $l^{p'}$

Comment: by doing this he again gets an $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ so I am guessing that it comes out from the fact that theses power sequences of 2 are l^1

Comment: I made an edit now we have $q>1$, this simplifies the problem since we don't have non integers in the sum (we can majorate by a serie which has integers in the powers of 2).

Comment: is $\sum_{i\in \mathbb Z} 2^{-\epsilon| i|}= 2\frac{1}{1-\frac 1{2^{\epsilon}}}-1=2\frac{2^{\epsilon}}{2^{\epsilon}-1}-1$ smaller than $\frac 1{\epsilon}$?

Comment: it doesn't seem so, I ploted this online.